# Union between ranges in scripting

Tags: python, scripting

Using random I am trying to get a random value from within two different ranges, say between 1 and 3 or 4 and 5. But random only seems to accept a single range. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm unclear about the parameters of your question. What proportion of the values would be between 1 and 3 versus 4 and 5? You could create a parametric equation with a jump discontinuity, but this problem sounds more like a stats or programming problem rather than Blender/graphics. What problem are you trying to solve with this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python random.uniform() function returns a randomly uniform number between 0 and 1. We can, if needed, map that number onto another distribution with another range by using the Cumulative Density Function (CDF) of the other distribution. Here you have asked for a function with a CDF in the range of [1-3] and [4-5]. For simplicity, I'm going to assume a uniform distribution:

[image: Plot of Input vs. Output]
In the plot above, the x values are from random.uniform() and the y values are from the cdf function below.

```
def cdf(t):
    if t < 0 or t > 1:
        raise ValueError("t must be [0, 1]")
    if t < 2/3.0:
        return ( 1 + t * 3.0 )
    else:
        return ( 3 + t * 3.2/2.0)
```

The code snippet below was used to generate the plot using the cdf function.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy import linspace
    
x = list(linspace(0, 1,  50))
y = [cdf(t) for t in x]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

At the cost of an additional call to `random.uniform` for each random number you want, here is a python script that will produce random numbers from an arbitrary list of intervals, either with an equal chance of the number coming from each interval, or with the choice of range weighted by the length of each interval, or with the choice of range weighted by an arbitrary list of weights

To reduce overhead, if you want weighted ranges, you should call `prepare_cumulative_weights` or `assign_cumulative_weights` once before any calls to `weighted choice`

This can be changed to only use one call to `random.uniform` for each random number, but the math is somewhat opaque, so I offer you the simpler but less efficient version.

````py
import random
from math import trunc

def unweighted_choice(intervals):
    """ Given a list of N tuples containing (start, end) intervals
        return a random number from one of the intervals.
        Each interval has a 1 in N chance of being used
    """
    n = trunc(random.uniform(0,len(intervals)))
    s = intervals[n]
    return random.uniform(s[0], s[1])


def prepare_cumulative_weights(intervals):
    """ Given a list of N tuples containing (start, end) intervals
        returns a list that uses the interval length of each tuple
        to assign it a cumulative position in a range that extends from 0 to
        the sum of all of the interval lengths.  This effectively assigns a
        weight to the tuple equivalent to the length of its interval.
    """
    weights = []
    t = 0.0
    for (s, e) in intervals:
        r = abs(s - e)
        t += r
        weights.append(t)
    return weights

def assign_cumulative_weights(raw_weights):
    """ Given a list of raw weights return a list of cumulative raw weights
    """
    weights = []
    t = 0.0
    for r in raw_weights:
        t += r
        weights.append(t)
    return weights

def weighted_choice(intervals, cumulative_weights):
    """ Given a list of N tuples containing (start, end) intervals
        and a list of cumulative weights, assigned from a monotic sequence
        returns a random number.  Each tuple has a chance of
        being selected from that is proportional to its weight.
    """
    f = random.uniform(0, cumulative_weights[-1])
    for n in range(0, len(cumulative_weights)):
        if cumulative_weights[n] > f:
            interval = intervals[n]
            return random.uniform(interval[0], interval[1])
    return -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    intervals = [(1, 3), (4, 5), (7, 11)]
    raw = [7, 1, 1]
    u = unweighted_choice(intervals)
    print(f'An unweighted choice {u}')
    cumulative_intervals = prepare_weights(intervals)
    for i in range(1,3):
        w = weighted_choice(intervals, cumulative_intervals)
        print(f'Length Weighted choice {i} {w}')
    cumulative_raw = assign_cumulative_weights(raw)
    for i in range(1,3):
        w = weighted_choice(intervals, cumulative_raw)
        print(f'Raw Weighted choice {i} {w}')
```
````